# Error installing a virtual printer driver on windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows, printing, driver, device-driver

I have developed a virtual printer driver in vc++.net and it is working fine in 32 bit environment. But while install it in win7 64 bit, it throws an error "**Operation could not be completed (error 0x800f0214)**" at the line

> rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "printername" /f "printer.inf" /r "printer port" /m "printer model" /hx64

Note: printerdriver.dll is compiled in 64bit.

Could you please help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: You'll probably get a better response on one of the other Stack Exchange sites - StackOverflow is intended for programming and software development questions.  

The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) tells you more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your INF file correct?? do verify it using INFGate.exe and there should be no errors reported by the tool.

If the INF file is correct, then it must be a signature issue, please note that signing is required for windows64 bit drivers, but not for 32 bit drivers.

In order to sign your driver, first make a cat file using inf2cat.exe and then use sign tool to sign the catalogue file... all these tools come with winddk...

have a look at this link for details on signing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544865(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: yes u r correct hjindal..
I corrected inf and now it is working as expected..
Thanks a lot!